# Listening to paste event on div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to upgrade an app using a [vis network](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/manipulation.html#) that displays a graph (using a canvas). The idea is to add a paste functionality, so that you could paste content from a different graph, or from a string.

I implemented a copy functionality based on navigator.clipboard. I attach an event handler to the document:

```
const copier = (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
  if (document.getSelection()?.type !== "Range") {
    // ...
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(JSON.stringify(graph));
  }
};

document.addEventListener("copy", copier)
```

This `if` is the only way I found to not interfere with "normal" copy events (selecting text outside the graph then CTRL + C for example). Not sure if it's ideal.

The real problem is with pasting. I can't just listen to "paste" events on `document` because I haven't found a way to identify that the paste is for the graph and not some other component in the app displayed at the same time (a text input for example).

I have tried the following:

- Attaching the event listener to the `div` container: doesn't catch the event
- Checking the `ClipboardEvent`'s `target` and `currentTarget`: they don't match the graph's `div` container, and results are inconsistent across browsers.
- Focusing the `div` before pasting (with `mydiv.focus()` and `tabIndex=1`), the paste is still not caught
- Using `contenteditable` on the `div`, but this messes with a lot of other things

After long searches and a lot of trials, I haven't found an answer to this.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Using contenteditable on the div, but this messes with a lot of other things":
What does it mess up? I believe that this is the best option next to reading it using js (the user will get a prompt to allow the paste reducing ease of use).

Comment: You can use a `keydown` and `keyup` handler on the html5 canvas element, that checks for the `ctrl` key, and then set a variable like `ctrldown` or something to true or false depending on said event listeners, and then check for a `keydown` or `keypress` of the `V` key. This would catch attempts to use keyboard shortcuts, but if you right-click paste, it would not register. 

Good question

Comment: Hard to explain what it messes up. Some text from vis.js that shouldn't be visible becomes visible (the default controls like "Add Node", etc.). I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `event delegation`?

```
document.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
    const graphContainer = document.getElementById("graph-container");
    if (graphContainer.contains(e.target)) {
        // Handle paste for the graph component
        // Process the pasted content here
    }
});
```